# Почему WrapPanel не работает внутри ScrollViewer с VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ориентация WrapPanel перекрывается. В результате вместо столбцов получается обычная прокрутка вниз.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="auto">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">        
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `WrapPanel` начинает класть элементы во второй столбец только если не хватает места по вертикали. Внутри `ScrollViewer`'а, откуда ей знать, сколько места по вертикали у самого `ScrollViewer`'а? `ScrollViewer` раздаёт всем бесконечно много места, так что места для внутренних элементов всегда хватает.

Уберите вертикальную скроллируемость, должно по идее помочь.

Comment: VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" отключает прокрутку . Если элементы захдят за правый край то их невидно. И не появляется горизонтальная прокрутка.

Comment: @codename0082016: Ну это уже новая проблема, правильно?

Comment: @codename0082016: Попробуйте `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">`.

Comment: непомогло. ничего не изменилось

Comment: @codename0082016: У меня работает. Проблема где-то у вас. Вангую, что ваш ScrollViewer бесконечный вправо.

Comment: @codename0082016: Попробуйте на тестовом приложении: https://pastebin.com/4uVmc6k3

Comment: вот здесь новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673020/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-wrappanel