# Не работает горизонтальная прокрутка WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Если элементы захдят за правый край то их невидно. И не работает горизонтальная прокрутка

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="auto">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">     
                        <Button Background="AliceBlue" Content="Кнопка 1" Height="250" />
                        <Button Background="Blue" Content="Кнопка 2" />
                        <Button Background="Aquamarine" Content="Кнопка 3" Width="60"/>   
                        ...
    </WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

без Width="auto" работает. Но как теперь auto заменить чтобы растягивалась до краёв экрана

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
    <ColumnDefinition  />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> //ScrollViewer находится здесь
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как размер (ColumnDefinition ScrollViewer ) сделать автоматическим до края экрана без auto?

Comment: У меня вот на таком примере работает: https://pastebin.com/4uVmc6k3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPDgL.png

Comment: без `Width="auto"` работает. Но как теперь auto заменить чтобы растягивалась до краёв экрана

Comment: У меня растягивается в примере.

Comment: добавлено в вопрос. у меня всё это внутри grid

Comment: Ну так уберите `Width="Auto"` из `ColumnDefinition`. `Width="Auto"` означает «бери ширины сколько хочешь», остальные подожмутся. Не удивительно, что `ScrollViewer` берёт бесконечно много.

Comment: тогда не будет растягиваться

Comment: Ну а так растягивается до бесконечности. Опишите в точности, какой layout вам надо.

Comment: первая постоянная. вторая меняет размер . третья заполняет до конца

Comment: Тогда `Width="*"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

после добавлния Width="0" и Width="*" заработало

```
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="auto">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
```